# Error- Tweets: no public messages in plugin Shortcodes Ultimate wordpress

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I am using *Shortcodes* Ultimate plugin in *wordpress*.
I have make changes in `wp-content/plugins/shortcodes-ultimate/lib/twitter.php`

using this

```
$messages = fetch_rss(
          'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=' . $username);
```

But it gives error

```
 Tweets: no public messages
```

What to do for this?

Comment: You need to update your Twitter widget.  API 1 was retired on 11th June https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-is-retired

Comment: Thanks for reply, But i am using [tweets username="twitter" limit="3" style="1" show_time="1"]  if not fine then how to update Twitter widget.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Friend You need to update your Plug-in. To Update your Plug-in Go to the Plug-in Tab. And search your Twitter plug-in click on that their you see the option of update the plug-in. After the Up-date of Plug-in. you can easily see the plug-in message Properly.